# How To Change admin user priviledge from creating an account for all users to users being able to create an account themselves in laravel

Tags: laravel

Good day Stack overflow, i am new to laravel and i created a project in which only admins can register users but now i want to change that logic to all users can register, Going about this without restarting the whole project is the only thing i am trying to achieve right now

```html
This is my handler.php file

<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string<Throwable>>
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the file to make the logic of registering the user.

Comment: There is nothing with the `handler.php` file. All you need to use `Laravel Gate` to authorize users for any specific routes or actions. Otherwise there are some popular built in packages which already handle role based permissions logic very well. Just need to use their convention and rock...

Have a look on this popular package:
```https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction```